# Uncaught TypeError javascript communicate with flash

Tags: javascript, html

I want to communicate with flash via javascript, to control my flash player 
here is my code but I have an error, would you please help me,

```
    var flashvars = {
        flvpVideoSource: "myApp.swf",
        flvpWidth: "640",
        flvpHeight: "360"
    };
    var params = {
        menu: "true",
        allowfullscreen: "true"
    };
    var attributes = {
        id: "FLVplayer",
        name: "FLVplayer"
    };


    //functions used to find the id of the flash object
    function getFlashMovieObject(movieName){
        if(document.embeds[movieName])
        return document.embeds[movieName];
        if(window.document[movieName])
        return window.document[movieName];
        if(window[movieName])
        return window[movieName];
        if(document[movieName])
        return document[movieName];
        return null;
    }

    //function in flash to play the video
    function playMyVideoInFlash(){
        var flashMovie = getFlashMovieObject("FLVplayer");
        flashMovie.playMyVideo();
    }

    //function in flash to pause the video
    function pauseMyVideoInFlash(){
        var flashMovie = getFlashMovieObject("FLVplayer");
        flashMovie.pauseMyVideo();
    }
    </script>
```

this is my error :

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'playMyVideo' of null index.html:37
playMyVideoInFlash index.html:37
onclick
```

my button code:

```
 <button type="button"  onclick="playMyVideoInFlash()">play</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="pauseMyVideoInFlash()">pause</button>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: seems like your flash not found (null) by JS

Answer (score 0):

use curly braces and it should work (or write in one line!), javascript automatically inserts a semicolon after each line!!!

with curly braces:

```
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName){
    if(document.embeds[movieName]) {
      return document.embeds[movieName];
    }
    if(window.document[movieName]) {
      return window.document[movieName];
    }
    if(window[movieName]) {
      return window[movieName];
    }
    if(document[movieName]) {
      return document[movieName];
    }
    return null;
}
```

one lines:

```
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName){
    if(document.embeds[movieName]) return document.embeds[movieName];
    if(window.document[movieName]) return window.document[movieName];
    if(window[movieName]) return window[movieName];
    if(document[movieName]) return document[movieName];
    return null;
}
```

you should also check for NULL in your functions (and probably if the playMyVideo/stopMyVideo-function exists), just because you return it in the getFlashMovieObject-Function:

```
 function playMyVideoInFlash(){
    var flashMovie = getFlashMovieObject("FLVplayer");
    if(typeof flashMovie === 'object' && typeof flashMovie.playMyVideo === 'function') {
      flashMovie.playMyVideo();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you added the checks which i recommended in the last part of my answer? you should do this and maybe add an "else" and log an error there. (your getFlashMovieObject-function probably returns null because nothing is found in the document and window...) is the FLVPlayer installed???

Comment: what do you mean by FLVPlayer installed?